# No sound after video card replaced (AMD Radeon HD 7770)

Tags: 12.04, sound, radeon

Issue:  **no sound**

**System:**

- Dual boot

  - Windows 7 (sda)
  - Ubuntu 12.04 (sdb)
- 2 harddrives
- Dell XPS 730
- Video card:  AMD Radeo HD 7770 Diamond Multimedia
- Sound card: Creative Labs SB X-Fi

**Additional info:**

- My sound used to work.
- Then, my old video card (NVIDIA geforce 280) died.
- I bought and installed a new video card:  Radeon HD 7770.
- After this, my sound no longer worked in ubuntu (Win7 audio still works).
- Everything else in ubuntu, such as video, works fine.
- I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the Radeon card includes sound capability.

**Problem Details:**

1. If I click on System Settings -> Sound, the panel freezes and stops responding indefinitely.
2. The sound volume icon at the top of the screen (by the clock) shows 3 dashes beside it "---", and an empty drop-down box shows if I click on it.
3. (Possibly related to 1.) When I reboot my machine, I get the message:   "gnome settings daemon not responding".  I have to force the reboot.
4. I reinstalled ubunbu (perserving my home directory) and the problem persists.

**Diagnostics info:**

Following procedure outlined here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

The following is a list of terminal commands, and their output:

$ aplay -l

> ```
> List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices
> ```

There is no listing beyond that, and the command freezes until I hit control-c

$ sudo aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: XFi [Creative X-Fi], device 0: ctxfi [Front/WaveIn]
  Subdevices: 256/256
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  ... repeats from #4 to #255
  Subdevice #255: subdevice #255
card 0: XFi [Creative X-Fi], device 1: ctxfi [Surround]
  Subdevices: 256/256
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  ... repeats from #4 to #255
  Subdevice #255: subdevice #255
card 0: XFi [Creative X-Fi], device 2: ctxfi [Center/LFE]
  Subdevices: 256/256
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  ... repeats from #4 to #255
  Subdevice #255: subdevice #255
card 0: XFi [Creative X-Fi], device 4: ctxfi [IEC958 Non-audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

> ```
> 00:0f.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP55 High Definition Audio
> (rev a2)  Subsystem: Dell Device 0224     Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast
> devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23     Memory at dfff0000 (32-bit,
> non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel
> driver in use: snd_hda_intel  Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
>
> -- 01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device aab0
> Subsystem: Diamond Multimedia Systems Device aab0     Flags: bus
> master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43    Memory at dfefc000 (64-bit,
> non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel
> driver in use: snd_hda_intel  Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
>
> -- 03:0a.0 Audio device: Creative Labs SB X-Fi    Subsystem: Creative Labs Device 6002
>   Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency
>   32, IRQ 18
> Memory at dbff4000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  Memory at
> dbc00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]     Memory at d4000000
> (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64M]     I/O ports at 8c00 [size=32]
>   Capabilities: <access denied>
> ```

Notice the Diamond Multimedia Systems Device - that seems to be my video card sound.  My video card is Diamond multimedia.

Also there's the weird NVIDIA device in there.  That must either be a remnant of my now removed NVIDIA graphics card, or else some kind of on-board thing.  Not sure which.

> ```
> **UPDATE** I disabled my onboard sound via the BIOS settings, 
> and now only 2 cards appear in this list.  The NVIDIA one is gone.
> ```

$ killall pulseaudio

- This allows me to open system settings -> sound.
- But the "Test Sound" button makes no sound
- And the output volume + mute controls are greyed / disabled at 0 volume.
- It also allows me to click on the sound control in the "task bar" (beside the clock), and a volume slider drops down, but it is disabled / greyed at 0 volume.

  ```
  $ find /lib/modules/uname -r | grep snd
  ```

> ```
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-88pm860x.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-tlv320aic3x.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8900.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8978.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-tlv320dac33.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm9090.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-sta32x.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-max98088.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-max9850.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-rt5631.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8903.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8580.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8523.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-max9877.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ads117x.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8955.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8804.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-sgtl5000.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8750.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm2000.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-tlv320aic32x4.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ak4642.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ad193x.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8753.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ak4535.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8985.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8350.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-dfbmcs320.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-cs42l51.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-tlv320aic26.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8737.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-uda1380.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8776.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8995.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-tpa6130a2.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8727.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm5100.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8991.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8510.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-jz4740-codec.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8400.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-lm4857.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8960.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-alc5623.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-cs4270.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-tlv320aic23.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8993.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8961.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8940.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-uda134x.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ad1836.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8994.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8782.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-cs4271.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8974.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8983.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8962.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ak4641.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm-hubs.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8971.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8996.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wl1273.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-adav80x.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-spdif.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-pcm3008.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-cx20442.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ak4671.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8711.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ad73311.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-max98095.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm9081.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8741.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm1250-ev1.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8988.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-adau1373.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8731.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-l3.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ssm2602.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-da7210.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ak4104.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8904.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8728.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8770.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-wm8990.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/soc/snd-soc-core.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/synth/emux/snd-emux-synth.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/synth/snd-util-mem.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/snd-hrtimer.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/oss/snd-mixer-oss.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/snd-page-alloc.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-dummy.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-virmidi.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-device.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-event.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-emul.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/snd.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/pcmcia/pdaudiocf/snd-pdaudiocf.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/pcmcia/vx/snd-vxpocket.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/usb/6fire/snd-usb-6fire.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/usb/snd-usbmidi-lib.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/usb/caiaq/snd-usb-caiaq.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/usb/usx2y/snd-usb-usx2y.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/usb/usx2y/snd-usb-us122l.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/usb/misc/snd-ua101.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/opl3/snd-opl3-synth.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/opl3/snd-opl3-lib.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/opl4/snd-opl4-lib.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/opl4/snd-opl4-synth.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-portman2x4.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-serial-u16550.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-mts64.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-mtpav.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/mpu401/snd-mpu401.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/mpu401/snd-mpu401-uart.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/vx/snd-vx-lib.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-dummy.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-aloop.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/pcsp/snd-pcsp.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-virmidi.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/firewire/snd-firewire-lib.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/firewire/snd-firewire-speakers.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/firewire/snd-isight.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/i2c/snd-tea6330t.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/i2c/other/snd-tea575x-tuner.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/i2c/other/snd-ak4113.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/i2c/other/snd-pt2258.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/i2c/other/snd-ak4117.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/i2c/other/snd-ak4xxx-adda.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/i2c/other/snd-ak4114.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/i2c/snd-cs8427.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/i2c/snd-i2c.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/pci/emu10k1/snd-emu10k1-synth.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/pci/emu10k1/snd-emu10k1.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/pci/emu10k1/snd-emu10k1x.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/pci/korg1212/snd-korg1212.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/pci/au88x0/snd-au8830.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/kernel/sound/pci/au88x0/snd-au8820.ko
>
> ... and 100+ more (deleted to keep underneath the post limit)
> ```

$ ps -ef | grep pulseaudio

> lightdm   1698  1659  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> lightdm   1700  1698  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> lightdm   1701  1700  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      1820  1800  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      1822  1820  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      1823  1822  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      1956     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      1979  1746  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
>
> sean      1981  1980  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2289     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2330     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2339     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2348     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2357     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2374     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2387     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2410     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2450     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2489     1  0 Nov29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
>
> sean      2627  2571  0 00:39 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulseaudio
>
> (I'm logged in as "sean")

**Update Info:  Nov 30th**

Here's a sequence of terminal commands and output performed after a reboot.

$ ps -ef | grep pulseaudio

```
lightdm   1717  1681  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

lightdm   1719  1717  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

lightdm   1720  1719  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      1840  1819  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      1842  1840  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      1843  1842  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      1935  1765  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11

sean      1952  1938  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      1984  1969  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      2427  2282  0 12:21 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulseaudio
```

$ pulseaudio -k; killall -KILL pulseaudio

```
pulseaudio(1717): Operation not permitted

pulseaudio(1719): Operation not permitted

pulseaudio(1720): Operation not permitted
```

$ ps -ef | grep pulseaudio

```
lightdm   1717  1681  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

lightdm   1719  1717  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

lightdm   1720  1719  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      1843     1  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      2449  2282  0 12:22 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulseaudio
```

$ sudo pulseaudio -k; killall -KILL pulseaudio

```
[sudo] password for sean: 

E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory /home/sean not ours.

E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: Permission denied

pulseaudio(1717): Operation not permitted

pulseaudio(1719): Operation not permitted

pulseaudio(1720): Operation not permitted
```

$ ps -ef | grep pulseaudio

```
lightdm   1717  1681  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

lightdm   1719  1717  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

lightdm   1720  1719  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      1843     1  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      2475  2282  0 12:23 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulseaudio
```

(can't seem to get that formatted right, but it's the same as above - running as sudo didn't kill extra processes)

$ pavucontrol

- this opens a window now (without the killall command above, it would just hang)
- but the window just says "Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait..." indefinitely

Also, after the killall command is executed:

- Now the volume control (by the clock) works
- I get a drop-down with a volume slider, Rhythmbox, and Sound Settings...
- I can now access sound settings without freezing up the window, either from

  - System Settings... -> Sound, or,
  - the volume control drop-down above.
- But, in the sound settings window...

  - "Output volume slider" is disabled/greyed
  - "Test Sound" button does nothing
  - "Play sound through" box is empty
  - "Record sound through" box is empty

$ sudo pulseaudio -k; sudo killall -KILL pulseaudio

```
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory /home/sean not ours.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: Permission denied
```

$ ps -ef | grep pulseaudio

```
lightdm   1720     1  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      1843     1  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog

sean      6233  6165  0 18:20 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulseaudio`
```

Comment: You seem to have 3 sound cards... maybe you should try using only one (pavucontrol should enable you to do so).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I installed pavucontrol, but when I try to launch it (either from the side-bar icon or from a terminal), it hangs, and no window appears.  I can see a "pavucontrol" process using ps -a, but there's no window.  Whatever is causing my system settings -> sound window to hang seems to be affecting pavucontrol too.

Comment: Does this return anything? And if so could you add the output to the post? `ps -ef | grep pulseaudio`

Comment: Done - added to the end of the top post.  Quite a bit of output from that.

Comment: I think I have an idea of the problem... try running this: `pulseaudio -k; killall -KILL pulseaudio`

Comment: Cool thanks for checking back MiJyn.  Added more info to the bottom of the original post, under "Update Info: Nov 30th"

Comment: Also - is there any way that I can disable/remove sound devices (other than through pavucontrol)?  Perhaps either through a config file or a terminal command?  Maybe if I remove all sound devices except the SB card, it will solve the problem.

Comment: hmm, try this instead (it seems like a permissions issue): `sudo pulseaudio -k; sudo killall -KILL pulseaudio`

Comment: That works a little better but still leaves some processes active.  No change in system behaviour.  Output added to original post.

Comment: Two more updates to the above post:  1.  If I run "sudo aplay -l", I get a bunch of output.  Output added to top post.  Note that without running with sudo, the command froze.  Also note that I get massive listings of subdevice #1 to #255.  2.  The second change is that I disabled my onboard sound via my BIOS settings, so now the lspci command just shows 2 video cards instead of 3 (the sound blaster one and the video card one).

Comment: And some more info:  running "sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav" works to make a sound.  It doesn't if I leave out the "sudo" part.  I also tried running "sudo chmod -R a+rwX /dev/snd" based on some info I read elsewhere, but that prevented me from being able to reboot into ubuntu properly through the graphical desktop, so I had to revert that by logging in through the non-graphical interface (via control-alt-F1)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my HP Envy 15 Laptop that also has a Radeon 7000 Mobile series card. This post is a partial solution to your problem in that, at least, your system will be running, but it will disable ALL usb sound-devices.

In /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, add this line to the end of the file:

```
blacklist snd-usb-audio
```

This solution lets me us my laptop very nicely now w/ AMD video acceleration, but w/o USB sound devices.  A better solution would be  some way to selectively disable USB devices on the AMD Radeon card, since the driver seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall and reinstall the gnome-sound-applet
it may help

open youe terminal and type

```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-sound-applet
```

it will uninstall the gnome-sound-applet and reinstall it .

Comment: Thanks for posting farhan.  When I type this command, here's what happens:

`$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-sound-applet`
`Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree`
`Reading state information... Done`
`E: Unable to locate package gnome-sound-applet`

I tried to search for gnome-sound-applet at this site:  http://packages.ubuntu.com/
and I couldn't find a hit.

Answer (score 0):

I had this identical problem.  I worked around it by adding the line:

```
blacklist snd-hda-codec-hdmi
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.  This is similar to user1798721's solution except that the problem is the HDMI sound device, apparently, not a USB sound device.

Of course, this disables the HDMI sound output. In my case, I am outputting the sound via SPDIF digital from the motherboard sound device to my sound system and only using HDMI for the video, so there is no loss.  But it would be nice to get this fixed.  Older kernel versions do not seem to have this problem on the same hardware.